# Which Maven Dependency need to add to use CloudBlobContainer fetchattributes()

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to use `fetchAttribute()`of `CloudBlobContainer`.
My question is which dependency do i need to use this method.

I use the code from [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-properties-metadata/)

Following are the dependency i already added in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

still its showing red line under `fetchAttribute()`and showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

Probably just the one you mentioned, according to:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cc%3A%22CloudBlobContainer%22

Maybe your artifact is not resolved correctly.

Check the following things: Is it in your local Maven repository? Can you open it and find the respective class file?

Answer (score 0):

@AnandDeshmukh, The dependency added in your `pom.xml` is correct (see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/)), but the codes in the article [Set and Retrieve Properties and Metadata](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-properties-metadata/) are written in C#, not Java.

The codes for Java as below, please see the methods of class `CloudBlobContainer` at http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobClient.html.

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("mycontainer");
// Get container properties
BlobContainerProperties properties = container.getProperties();
System.out.println(container.getStorageUri().getPrimaryUri());
System.out.println(properties.getLastModified());
System.out.println(properties.getEtag());
// Get the container metadata
HashMap<String, String> metaData = container.getMetadata();
for(String key: metaData.keySet()) {
    String value = metaData.get(key);
    System.out.println(key+":"+value);
}
// Using CloudBlobContainer.setMetadata(HashMap<String,String> metadata) for set metadata for container
```

As reference, you can refer to the Javadocs of Azure Storage SDK for Java at http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/.

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> metaData = container.getMetadata(HashMap<String,String> metadata);` showing error saying `HashMap cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh Sorry for my mistake that the function `getMetadata()` without any parameter. I want to tell you that you can use  the function `setMetadata(HashMap<String,String> metadata)`  to set metadata for a container, but mistake to add the parameter `HashMap<String,String> metadata` for the getting function. I has updated my post.

Comment: I tried something like `HashMap<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
 metadata.put("Test", "Dummy meta data");
 blob.setMetadata(metadata);
 container.setMetadata(metadata);
System.out.println(container.getMetadata());`

Comment: It is showing `{Test=Dummy meta data}` at `System.out.println(container.getMetadata());` but how can i check weather it is been stored in azure. I am using Azure Storage explorer

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh, I don't understand what the "weather" you said means. Is it a blob stored in a container of Azure Blob Storage. If you want to show the content of a blob, you need to download it for displaying. Please refer to the tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/#download-a-blob. If the block blob has text content, you can use the function [`downloadText`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/#download-a-blob) to get the content string.